# How to set color of table-striped for large rows (large row with multiple lines)

Tags: html, html-table, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-table

I am trying to separate the background color of table row with gray and white. However, the table has a large row with multiple small rows inside it using rowspan="x". Is there any way to change the background color for large row and small rows inside it?

I cannot set the background manually because the number of rows inside are dynamically.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4hi6.jpg)

```
     <table class="table table-striped table-bordered reportTable" id="contentToConvert">
        <thead style="text-align: center">
           <tr>
              <th scope="col" rowspan="2" style="width: 10%; vertical-align: middle;">Order #</th>
              <th scope="col" rowspan="2" style="width: 20%; vertical-align: middle;">Customer Information</th>
              <th scope="col" rowspan="2" style="width: 10%; vertical-align: middle;">Package(s)</th>
              <th scope="col" colspan="5" style="width: 60%; vertical-align: middle;">Package Information</th>
           </tr>
           <tr>
              <th style="width: 15%; vertical-align: middle">Tracking Number</th>
              <th style="width: 10%; vertical-align: middle">Size</th>
              <th style="width: 10%; vertical-align: middle">Weight</th>
              <th style="width: 15%; vertical-align: middle">Instructions</th>
              <th style="width: 10%; vertical-align: middle">Status</th>
           </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
           <tr>
              <td rowspan="5">RetailOrder_12513413</td>
              <td rowspan="2" style="padding-left: 1rem">
                 John Doe <br>
                 123 street <br>
                 Akron OH 44307<br>
                 123-456-7890<br>
                 john.doe@gmail.com
              </td>
              <td rowspan="2" style="text-align: center">5</td>
              <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle">018635013640123401234</td>
              <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle">5 / 5/ 5 inches</td>
              <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle">10 lbs 10 oz</td>
              <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle"></td>
              <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle">Delivered</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
              <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle">018635013640123401234</td>
              <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle">5 / 5/ 5 inches</td>
              <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle">10 lbs 10 oz</td>
              <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle">Leave at front door</td>
              <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle">Delivered</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
              <td rowspan="2">RetailOrder_0023</td>
              <td rowspan="2" style="padding-left: 1rem">
                 George Jason <br>
                 123 Arlington street <br>
                 Arlington VA 22222<br>
                 123-456-7890<br>
                 GEORGE.Jason@gmail.com
              </td>
              <td rowspan="2" style="text-align: center">3</td>
              <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle">5134134231231261341231</td>
              <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle">5 / 5/ 5 inches</td>
              <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle">10 lbs 10 oz</td>
              <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle"></td>
              <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle">Delivered</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
              <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle">018635013640123401234</td>
              <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle">5 / 5/ 5 inches</td>
              <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle">10 lbs 10 oz</td>
              <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle">Leave at front door</td>
              <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle">Delivered</td>
           </tr>
        </tbody>
     </table>
```

Answer (score 2):

this code will give your table alternate color

```
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

Comment: It's not working in my case, please see my screenshot, the table contains large rows, with rowspan="x", is there any way to make each large row have same background color?